# No se muestran los datos JSON que vienen del backend con Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, spring-data

Los datos provenientes del backend no se muestran al hacer la petición al servidor.

Tengo la Entidad:

```
@Entity
public class Proof {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    public Proof() {

    }

    public Proof(Long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

El Repositorio:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ProofRepository extends JpaRepository<Proof, Long> {
}
```

El Controlador:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class ProofController {

    private ProofRepository proofRepository;

    public ProofController(ProofRepository proofRepository) {
        this.proofRepository = proofRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/api/proof")
    public List<Proof> findAll(){
        return proofRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

En la clase Main añado un registro que se guarda y se muestra por consola. Pero al hacer la petición desde Postman me devuelve un objeto vacío

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La causa de que datos no se muestran es que no has colocado los getters en tu entidad `Proof`. Tu entidad debería lucir:

```java
@Entity
public class Proof {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    public Proof() {
    }

    public Proof(Long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Asegúrate también de que la tabla Proof en tu base de datos contenga información y no esté vacía.

Comment: Genial, exactamente ese era el problema, muchas gracias.